# Physics body wont be created for my textures in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using Spritekit and I am adding .png photos from photoshop. I am trying to add a physics body to a texture but when the simulator runs the sprite node is stagnant and it gives me the error "physics body could not be created". What do I do to fix this? Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  let blueball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "purpBall")


  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    blueball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)


    blueball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: blueball.texture!, size: blueball.size)
    blueball.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    addChild(blueball)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it only happened in the simulator. On a physical device it worked fine.

I ended up creating a CGPath for the SKPhysicsNodes so I could continue using the different device simulators

Use this to create the CGPaths

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SpriteKit Tools - SKPhysicsBody Path Generator (Swift version 5.2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        /* disable responsive */
        .container {
            max-width: none;
            width: 970px;
        }

            #sprite {
                background-color: #eee;
                position: absolute;
            }
            #path {
                cursor: crosshair;
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>SKPhysicsBody Path Generator</h1>
            <p class="lead">SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path) Here is a small helper for easier path drawing.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h5>Basic Instruction</h5>
                    <ol>
                        <li><small>Drag and drop the sprite image into drop zone.</small></li>
                        <li><small>Start drawing path by clicking on coordinates.</small></li>
                        <li><small>Path need to be as a convex polygonal path with counterclockwise winding.</small></li>
                        <li><small>No self intersections.</small></li>
                        <li><small>The points are specified relative to the owning node’s origin.</small></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>


            <hr>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="resetShape()">Reset Shape</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="location.reload()">Reset All</button>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleRetinaMode()" id="retinaCheckbox" checked> Retina? (please check before declaring path)
            <br><br>

            <canvas id="sprite" width="940" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="path" width="0" height="100"></canvas>

            <p class="text-muted"><small>X:<span id="tooltipX">0</span> Y:<span id="tooltipY">0</span></small></p>
            <br>

            <h5>Output</h5>
<pre>
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "codeImgName")
let path = CGMutablePath()
let offsetX = sprite.size.width * sprite.anchorPoint.x
let offsetY = sprite.size.height * sprite.anchorPoint.y

<span id="codeCGPath"></span>
path.closeSubpath()
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
</pre>
        </div>

        <script>
// reference from http://davidwalsh.name/resize-image-canvas

var spriteCanvas = document.getElementById('sprite');
var spriteContext = spriteCanvas.getContext('2d');
spriteContext.fillText('Drop Sprite Image Here', 400, 50);

var pathCanvas = document.getElementById('path');
var pathContext = pathCanvas.getContext('2d');

function render(src){
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
        spriteContext.clearRect(0, 0, spriteCanvas.width, spriteCanvas.height);
        spriteCanvas.width = image.width;
        spriteCanvas.height = image.height;
        spriteContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

        pathContext.clearRect(0, 0, pathCanvas.width, pathCanvas.height);
        pathCanvas.width = image.width;
        pathCanvas.height = image.height;
    };
    image.src = src;
}

function loadImage(src){

    if(!src.type.match(/image.*/)){
        console.log('Dropped file is not image format');
        return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        render(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(src);

    var fileName = src.name;
    var codeImgName = document.getElementById('codeImgName');
    codeImgName.innerHTML = fileName;
}

spriteCanvas.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, true);

spriteCanvas.addEventListener('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadImage(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}, true);


var retinaMode = true;
function toggleRetinaMode(){
    var status = document.getElementById('retinaCheckbox');

    retinaMode = status.checked ? true : false;
}



var actualX = 0;
var actualY = 0;
var displayX = document.getElementById('tooltipX');
var displayY = document.getElementById('tooltipY');

pathCanvas.onmousemove = function(e){
    actualX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    actualY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    displayX.innerHTML = retinaMode ? Math.floor(actualX / 2) : actualX;
    displayY.innerHTML = retinaMode ? Math.floor((spriteCanvas.height - actualY - 1) / 2) : spriteCanvas.height - actualY - 1;
}

var pathArray = new Array();
pathCanvas.onclick = function(e){
    var coor = {
        actualX: actualX,
        actualY: actualY,
        displayX: displayX.innerHTML,
        displayY: displayY.innerHTML,
    };
    pathArray.push(coor);
    refreshShape(pathArray);
}

var codeCGPath = document.getElementById('codeCGPath');
function refreshShape(pathArray){

    pathContext.clearRect(0, 0, pathCanvas.width, pathCanvas.height);

    pathContext.beginPath();

    for(var i in pathArray){
        if(i == 0) {
            pathContext.moveTo(pathArray[i].actualX, pathArray[i].actualY);
            codeCGPath.innerHTML = 'path.move(to: CGPoint(x:  '+pathArray[i].displayX+' - offsetX, y: '+pathArray[i].displayY+' - offsetY))<br>';
            continue;
        }
        pathContext.lineTo(pathArray[i].actualX, pathArray[i].actualY);
        codeCGPath.innerHTML += 'path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: '+pathArray[i].displayX+' - offsetX, y: '+pathArray[i].displayY+' - offsetY))<br>';
    }

    pathContext.closePath();
    pathContext.lineWidth = 1;
    pathContext.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    pathContext.stroke();
    pathContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
    pathContext.fill();
}

function resetShape(){
    pathArray = new Array();
    codeCGPath.innerHTML = null;
    pathContext.clearRect(0, 0, pathCanvas.width, pathCanvas.height);
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```